# $\pi$ in terms of polygamma

Tags: nt.number-theory, experimental-mathematics

The computer found this, but couldn't prove it.

Let $\psi(n,x)$ denote the polygamma function.

With precision 500 decimal digits we have:

$$ \pi^2 = \frac{1}{4}(15 \psi(1, \frac13) - 3 \psi(1, \frac16)) $$

Is it true?

In machine readable form:

```
 pi^2 == 1/4*(15*psi(1, 1/3) - 3*psi(1, 1/6))
```

Comment: Both sides are periods, so maybe someday the computer will also get an algorithm to prove it or disprove it.

Comment: Boils down easily to $\zeta(2)$ calculation.

Comment: I have the following similar conjectures: $$\psi\left(2,\frac16\right)-9\psi\left(2,\frac13\right)-52\zeta(3)=0$$ and $$\psi\left(3,\frac16\right)-17\psi\left(3,\frac13\right)+480\zeta(4)=0.$$

Comment: More conjectural formula: $$\psi\left(4,\frac16\right)-33\psi\left(4,\frac13\right)-5808\zeta(5)=0.$$

Comment: $$\psi\left(5,\frac16\right)-65\psi\left(5,\frac13\right)+87360\zeta(6)=0,$$ $$\psi\left(6,\frac16\right)-129\psi\left(6,\frac13\right)-1573920\zeta(7)=0.$$

Comment: In general, I conjecture that for each positive integer $m$ there are integers $a_m$ and $b_m$ such that $$\psi\left(m,\frac16\right)=a_m\psi\left(m,\frac13\right)+b_m\zeta(m+1).$$

Comment: Include notation ... $\psi(m,x) = \psi^{(m)}(x)$ the $m$th derivative of $\psi$, and the digamma function $\psi(x)$ is $\Gamma'(x)/\Gamma(x)$.

Comment: For investigating $\pi^2 = \frac{1}{4}(15 \psi(1, \frac13) - 3 \psi(1, \frac16))$, perhaps first we should ask whether $\psi(1, \frac13)$ and $\psi(1, \frac16))$ have closed forms.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar In general $\psi (1,a/N) $ can be expressed in terms of Dirichlet L-values $L (\chi,2) $ for some characters $\chi $ modulo $N $. Taking the linear combination we are interested in, the odd characters cancel, leaving only the even ones for which the L-value is proportional to $\zeta (2) $.

Comment: Related, found potential closed form for psi(2,1/6) and psi(4,1/6): https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312550/psi2-1-6-psi4-1-6-in-terms-of-zeta-and-pi-only-and-another-closed-form-f

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Note that 
$$ 
\psi(m,x) =(-1)^{m+1} m! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x+k)^{m+1}}.
$$ 
Therefore 
$$ 
\psi(m,1/6) = (-1)^{m+1} m! \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(k+1/6)^{m+1}} =(-1)^{m+1} m! 6^{m+1} \sum_{n\equiv 1 \mod 6} \frac{1}{n^{m+1}}. 
$$ 
Writing the condition $n\equiv 1 \mod 6$ as $n\equiv 1 \mod 3$ but not $4 \mod 6$, the above is 
\begin{align*}
&(-1)^{m+1} m! 6^{m+1} \Big( \sum_{n\equiv 1 \mod 3} \frac{1}{n^{m+1}} - \frac{1}{2^{m+1}} \sum_{n\equiv 2 \mod 3} \frac{1}{n^{m+1}}\Big)\\
&= 2^{m+1} \psi(m,1/3)-\psi(m,2/3). 
\end{align*}
We also have 
$$
\psi(m,1/3) +\psi(m,2/3) = (-1)^{m+1} m! 3^{m+1} \sum_{n \not\equiv 0\mod 3} \frac{1}{n^{m+1}} = (-1)^{m+1} m! (3^{m+1} -1) \zeta(m+1). 
$$
From these two relations, clearly we have a linear relation connecting $\psi(m,1/6)$, $\psi(m,1/3)$ and $\zeta(m+1)$: namely, 
$$ 
\psi(m,1/6) = (2^{m+1}+1) \psi(m,1/3)+(-1)^m m! (3^{m+1}-1) \zeta(m+1).
$$

Comment: Thank you. Is there simpler closed form for psi(1,1/3) or psi(1,1/6)?. psi(1,1/4) is directly related to catalan and pi.

Comment: I managed to express psi(2,1/6),psi(4,1/6) in terms of zeta, pi,sqrt(3) only:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/312550/psi2-1-6-psi4-1-6-in-terms-of-zeta-and-pi-only-and-another-closed-form-f

Comment: @joro We have for example $\psi(1,1/3)=2\pi^2/3+9L(\chi,2)/2$ where $\chi$ is the non-trivial character mod 3, see my answer to the question in your last comment. I know of no closed form for $L(\chi,2)$ itself and I don't expect there is one (which is not trivially equivalent) but these are definitely interesting numbers.